# TS cookies in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have an asp.net C# web app.

When I deploy it on local VM (IIS 7.5) it shows only one cookie (ASP.NET_SessionId) comes which is fine.

But if I am putting my app on live server it showing two below cookies, can someone tell me where and why this TS cookie is coming from?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. This cookie was coming from firewall application server. In production environment there is a firewall application server (doesn't know much about the configuration of this firewall app server) but this cookie was being generated by that server.